# How to search in json with jq?

Tags: json, jq

How can I output just the `duration` values from below?

If I search for `jq -r ".media.duration"` then I get `nil`.

```
$ cat test.json | jq -r ".episodes[1:]" 
[
  {
    "uniqueHash": "a2dc48cd0f9",
    "startOffset": "{0}",
    "media": {
      "720p": {
        "extension": "mp4",
        "filesize": "1702",
        "duration": "00:51:55",
      },
    }
  },
  {
    "uniqueHash": "a2d0f9",
    "startOffset": "{0}",
    "media": {
      "720p": {
        "extension": "mp4",
        "filesize": "12602",
        "duration": "00:51:55",
      },
    }
  },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map()`:

```
$ cat test.json | jq -r '.episodes[1:] | map(.media["720p"].duration)'
[
  "00:51:55",
  "00:51:55"
]
```

Because `.episodes[1:]` gives you a list, you need to iter over it. [`map(<selector>)`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)) is what you want here.

Alternatively, you could flatten the list using [`.[]`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.[]):

```
$ cat test.json | jq -r ".episodes[1:] | .[] | .media[\"720p\"].duration" 
00:51:55
00:51:55
```

---

The above solutions assume you always have `720p`. This might not always be the case, so you can use [`to_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) to get all resolutions:

```
$ cat test.json | jq -r ".episodes[1:] | map(.media|to_entries[]|.value.duration)"
[
  "00:51:55",
  "00:51:55"
]
```

Comment: For your second solution I get `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:` when adding `[\"720p\"]`. Works uptill `".episodes[1:] | .[] | .media"`.

Comment: @JasmineLognnes do you use double quotes for the whole expression? You must either use `"... [\"720p\"] ..."` (double quotes + escape inner double quotes) or `'... ["720p"] ...'` (single quotes).

Answer (score 2):

You still need to get to that point; you haven't done the `jq` equivalent of `cd` or anything. You need to flatten the array returned by `episodes[1:]` by adding another set of brackets. Also, you skipped the resolution level (`"720p"`).  Putting that all together, this should work. It will output one duration value per line, unquoted:

```
jq -r '.episodes[1:][].media["720p"].duration'
```

Note that you can't use the dot syntax on `720p` (*`media.720p.duration`) because that key starts with a digit.

Note that your JSON snippet is technically invalid; strict JSON doesn't allow commas at the end of a list. I corrected that and wrapped a structure it to match your query:

```
{
  "episodes": [
    {},
    {
      "uniqueHash": "a2dc48cd0f9",
      "startOffset": "{0}",
      "media": {
        "720p": {
          "extension": "mp4",
          "filesize": "1702",
          "duration": "00:51:55"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "uniqueHash": "a2d0f9",
      "startOffset": "{0}",
      "media": {
        "720p": {
          "extension": "mp4",
          "filesize": "12602",
          "duration": "00:51:55"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Running `jq -r '.episodes[1:][]|.media["720p"].duration'` on the above yields this output:

```
00:51:55
00:51:55
```

Comment: `episodes[1:]` is a list, so `episodes[1:].media` won’t work. See my answer using `map()` instead.

Comment: I get `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index array with string "media"`.

Comment: ah, you're right, I extra brackets. You need `episodes[1:][].media`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation using [tostream](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tostream).  If the (slightly corrected) sample data is in `data.json` then the command

```
$ jq -Mr ' 
    tostream                        # generate [[path],value] pairs from input
  | select(length==2) as [$p,$v]    # assign [path] to $p and value to $v
  | select($p[-1]=="duration")      # keep paths ending in "duration"
  | $v                              # emit value
' data.json
```

produces

```
00:51:55
00:51:55
```

This should work on the original JSON data as well as the `.media.duration` sample data subtree.

Comment: This is great -- works regardless of tree depth. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to pull any `duration` value in your json tree, you could just recurse and try to pull the `duration` discarding null results.

```
.. | objects.duration? // empty
```

To be more explicit and only pull `duration` values, you could analyze the paths to the values and select the `duration` values only.

```
getpath(leaf_paths | select(.[-1] == "duration"))
```